# strange behavior of a telegram bot on python

Tags: python, aiogram

I am writing a telegram bot on python and aiogram3. And a strange problem appeared. At some point, the bot stopped responding to the command.

The logs contain the following message:
`INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=798588584 is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=6724341043.`

There were no changes in the code. I also tried to find a solution in ethernet, but couldn't find anything. Then I just created a new project. And copied all the code from the old one. The result has not changed . But at some point after the next launch of the bot in a new project, it began to respond to commands. I checked the old project again, and the bot still did not respond to commands there. I will provide the code below, it is identical in two projects.

file bot_create

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

bot = Bot('6724341043:AAEK51DMwxmFqy8rBTThNvJ43xq9AG-Gaq4')
dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
```

file bot_start

```py
import asyncio

import logging
import sys
from bot_create import dp, bot

from data_base import sql_db



async def main():
    
    sql_db.sql_db_start()

    await dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

file handlers admin

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
from os import getenv

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import router
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold
from bot_create import dp
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from data_base import sql_db
import bot_text


class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    question = State()
    answer = State()
    admins = State()


@dp.message(Command(bot_text.start_moderator.lower()))
async def start_command(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(FSMAdmin.admins)
    await message.answer(bot_text.start_admin)


@dp.message(FSMAdmin.admins)
async def start_admin(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text in bot_text.key_world:
        context_date = str(message.from_user.id)
        await sql_db.sql_add_admin(context_date)
        await message.answer("доступ разрешен")


    else:
        await message.answer("ошибка в кодовом слове")

    await state.clear()


@dp.message(Command(bot_text.add_question_command.lower()))
async def add_question(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    admins = await sql_db.is_admin()
    if str(message.from_user.id) in ((admin[0]) for admin in admins):
        await message.answer(bot_text.add_question)
        await state.set_state(FSMAdmin.question)
    else:
        print(str(message.from_user.id))
        print(admins)
        await message.answer("no")


@dp.message(FSMAdmin.question)
async def note_question(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(question=message.text)
    await message.answer(bot_text.add_answer)
    await state.set_state(FSMAdmin.answer)


@dp.message(FSMAdmin.answer)
async def add_answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    count = await sql_db.count()
    data = await state.get_data()
    data["answer"] = message.text
    data["number"] = count + 1
    print(data)
    await sql_db.sql_add_question(data)
    await message.answer(bot_text.save_question)
    await state.clear()
```

I couldn't find anything on this issue.